# Create a string field from an iterable string field as it is consumed

Tags: python, iterator, generator, pydantic, iterable

I have the following model:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from collections.abc import AsyncIterable

class Message(BaseModel):
    content_iterable: AsyncIterable[str]
    content: str | None = None
```

`content_iterable` is an iterator that needs to be consumed by a client.

I would like `content` to be set as the full result of `content_iterable` once it has been consumed.

A client to my API will be consuming `content_iterable`, so I cannot simply consume it in my app and then set the result to `content`.

Is this possible?